# Running MSI installers silently

Tags: merge, exe, silent, windows-installer

I am having 3 files -

1. Alky for Applications.msi ( which make Vista Apps work on XP)
2. Windows VIsta sidebar.exe ( Which make that VIsta sidebar work on XP)
   3.Gadget Extractor.msi ( A part of number 2)

I just want to have all the setups installed by just instlaling one. One of my freind told me that the **MSI packages may be silently installed using /qb switch
the .exe I got there is NSIS setup which may be silently installed using /S switch.**

SO I am a total **n00b** in software developing ,so pls suggest me what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to create a batch file and put these commands in it to launch the installers:

```
msiexec /i "C:\Users\ZippyV\Desktop\Alky for Applications.msi" /quiet
"C:\Users\ZippyV\Desktop\Windows VIsta sidebar.exe" /s
msiexec /i "C:\Users\ZippyV\Desktop\Gadget Extractor.msi" /quiet
```

Change the extension of the batch file to .cmd and put all the files in the same directory.

EDIT: make sure to specify the full path to your installers and use quotes around them. To run the file, just click it.

Comment: Thanks a lot , but do I need to specify the file location and if yes how ? and are you sure it will work ? coz I tried this msiexec /qb <b>C:\Users\Netizen\Desktop\Windows Sidebar for Windows XP - Package by Joshoon(www.djjoshoon.com)\Installer.msi</b> but didnt work !

Comment: You need to specify the full path and because it contains spaces put quotes " around the path.

Comment: Since you are using Windows XP you need to use the folder "Documents and Settings" instead of "Users". (I'm using Vista)

Comment: Thanks a lot ZippyV - Can I have your email if possible ?